# SignalR Core detect if connection is closed by client or server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-signalr

On ASP.NET Core 2.1 LTS, there is [no automatically reconnect for SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-2.1#reconnect-clients). So I implemented it on my own using [`onclose` event of the js client](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/javascript/api/@aspnet/signalr/hubconnection?view=signalr-js-latest#onclose). While this works, it has a side-effect: The client also trys to reconnect, when the connection is cancelled by the client itself - for example when closing the browser tab.

The reconnect works for a short period of time, until the tab is closed. Since I'm re-loading notifications on re-connect to keep the user up to date in such a case, this is a waste of ressources since I do several SQL queries on a user that closes the tab.

```
let reconnectWaitTime = 5000
let client = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/overviewHub")
    .build();
client.onclose(async (e) => {
    await tryReconnect(client)
    notificationsManager.handleReConnect()
})

await tryReconnect(client)
let notificationsManager = new ULNotificationsManager(client)

async function tryReconnect(client,) {
    try {
        let started = await client.start()
        return started;
    } catch (e) {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, reconnectWaitTime));
        return await tryReconnect(client)
    }
}
```

**How can I detect if the connection was closed from the client or the server, so that I'm able to only reload the notification data if the server closed the connection?**

### Approach

[According to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@aspnet/signalr/hubconnection?view=signalr-js-latest#onclose), there should be an `Error` callback for the `onclose` method:

```
client.onclose(function(ev){
    console.warn(ev)
})
```

My idea was to use this error for getting more detailled information like some error code that let me filter out the client side abort. But this doesn't seem work, I got `undefined` in my logs.

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

My solution seems not to work in all cases. For example. when the `dotnet` console window is closed, there is no exception and so also no reconnect. I assume that .NET core is properly closing the connections in this case.

I tried working around this by overriding the `Dispose` method of the hub, calling some event on the client that triggery my reconnect. Doesnt't work well. I ended in using the `window.onbeforeunload` event to detect if the user navigates away

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    window.userIsNavigatingAway = true
    return
};
```

and check for this boolean instead of the closing error

```
client.onclose(async (error) => {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/57833660/3276634
    if (!window.userIsNavigatingAway) {
        await tryReconnect(client, initialReConnectWaitTime)
        console.log('ReConnect worked')
        notificationsManager.handleReConnect()
    } else {
        console.log("Client closed the WS connection, so no reconnect attemp is made")
    }
})
```

### Original answear

*This only works if the server was killed unexpectedly*.

Found out that the Error callback refers to server side issues: When the connection is aborted by the server (e.g. server restart), I get an `Error` object:

```
 Error: "WebSocket closed with status code: 1006 ()."
```

So my problem could be easily solved by checking if the error is undefined:

```
client.onclose(async (error) => {
    if (typeof error !== 'undefined') {
        await tryReconnect(client)
        notificationsManager.handleReConnect()
    } else {
        console.log("Client closed the WS connection, so no reconnect attemp is made")
    }
})
```

I'll have to try if this also works correct when the client lost network connection (e.g. on mobile devies), where a reconnect would be usefull.